# Video of a person doing Qigong where somehow many others cannot lift him easily?

Tags: tricks

I remember that a few years ago, I watched a YouTube video about Qigong. In that video, there is a man who cannot be lifted easily by other people when he does not use Qigong force, but when he does use his Qigong force, somehow others cannot lift him easily anymore. I tried to search for that video again, but couldn't find it.

Also, do you believe in what that man did in the video? If that is true, then Einstein theories needs to be modified, as people found a new force besides gravity and nuclear force.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about martial arts

Comment: " then Einstein theories needs to be modified " (facepalm)

Comment: Well, I for one think it does deserve some discussion here in a martial arts forum, because this sort of thing goes on a lot in martial arts as proof of the existence of chi energy and the ability to use it by doing martial arts and chi-kung. It's certainly bogus stuff akin to magic, but it needs to be shown for what it is in order to make sure people don't waste any of their time on it.

Comment: Annie Abbot, aka "The Georgia Magnet", circa 1884, toured and performed hot on the heels of Lulu Hurst, the original "Georgia Wonder". It's a practiced feat of leverage and center of gravity, and has nothing to do with Chi/Qi.

Answer (score 6):

I guess you mean something like [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QZ9InzTLNjs) or [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-GkeCTS2Zok).
There are other examples like this on youtube.

It has nothing to do with Qiqong or Chi, but with the timing, focus and mindset of the people who are trying to lift. The trick is called [Finger lift](http://www.abc.net.au/science/articles/2008/05/27/2257305.htm) or [Light as a feather, stiff as a board trick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_as_a_feather,_stiff_as_a_board)

The explanation is that the first time around people don't believe they can lift someone with just 2 fingers and their effort is not very coordinated. At the second attempt the people are more focused, believe they can do it and start lifting all at the same time, which makes it easier.

Answer (score 4):

THelper has some great links and information, to which I will add a couple other factors:

- when someone prepares to lift something they suspect they may not be able to lift, they tend to position themselves so their arms are tucked in tightly against the body, hoping to have more of the leg and core strength transfer through to the hand doing the lifting.  When primed to lift like this, there's normally a short range of motion that's very strong, so you can lift by perhaps 5cm from the starting position before you'd need to reposition yourself.  If the person they're trying to lift ensures that from the starting position they have room to just relax and let the exact body parts being pushed move the 5 cms without stiffening and letting the lifting power transfer through that limb to the body itself - for example by letting an elbow that was initially downwards rotate towards their back - then there's no net lifting effect on their centre of mass.  After someone's made their attempt, there's the psychological question of whether they'll say "yeah well, that didn't mean anything - let me reposition myself and try again" - but the "performer" will already be indicating the demonstration is over....  Another perspective on the same thing: if you really wanted to lift an unconscious person you'd sling them over your back or something and get your centre of mass in close and expect to have to lift up until you feel them dragging downwards and they're all stretched out and start to lift off the ground, but with someone you know is conscious, and who's giving you instructions about how and where to lift, you'll likely be expecting more resistance / cooperation.
- if your hands are touch someone and you start to tense in preparation to push/lift, and see the other person is also tensing, you'll get a feeling of muscular effort before you've actually even tried to move, just from having your antagonist muscles engaged.  If the other person then relaxes, there's a split second where you have to either relax the antagonists and start actually pushing, or you keep the tension there without moving.  Your nervous system is actually surprisingly comfortable just doing that latter, and psychologically it can seem like the "right" thing to do in that situation, then you're tensing against a relaxed limb for no particular reason and they're feeling clever....